# LockMode:None in DQL with method CreateQuery for Doctrine 2.5

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

do not know how to use the LockMode making a dql with the following method:

```
EntityManager-> createQuery ('current DQL')
```

Someone can give me an example.

My DQL example is:

```
SELECT c FROM JbxModelBundle:Categoria c
```

But I do not like using LockMode find unused methods.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to your question.  Are you trying to change the LockMode?

Comment: Yes. The problem is what in Doctrine 2.5 and sql Server the default value for LockMode is null and is necesary for my project what is NONE because is a API /REST system and produces locks in sql. And i not find how implements for method CreateQuery and getResult, only exists in examples for find method. Now is imposible change this method in my project. Thanks and sorry for my english.